# Finding the balancing point of a subsequence

Tags: python, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded

This is a little tricky to explain, so bear with me.

Suppose you have an integer `X` and a list of integers `A`.  Let `` A` `` be a copy of `A` where all values `A[i] != X` are replaced by `-X`.  For example,

```
X = 5
A = [1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 1, 8]
```

would result in

```
A` = [-5, -5, 5, 5, -5, 5, -5, -5, -5]
```

The task is to find a subsequence `B` of `` A` `` that sums to 0 when the middle
item of `B` is removed from the summation.  With the previous example we would have

```
B = [-5, 5, 5, -5, 5, -5, -5]
```

where the middle item is `-5` at index 4 (of `` A` ``).  Splitting that into two lists generates

```
[-5, 5, 5] | [5, -5, -5]
```

which clearly sum to 0.  If such a subsequence `B` exists then the program should return the index of that middle value, plus 1.  In this case the return value would be `5`.

I have a working solution, however it has pretty bad time complexity:

> 4.64179955720276e-05 for 15 elements
>
> 0.003033149677870525 for 115 elements
>
> 0.15060318663344355  for 1015 elements
>
> 13.662074328908023   for 10015 elements

It is supposed to scale up to 100,000 elements, and I think that would take about 19 minutes in the current state.  I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on how I could simplify, improve, and speed up my algorithm.

```
from collections import deque

def equi ( trim_list ):
    popped_total = sum(trim_list)
    j = popped_total
    k = 0
    center = 0
    for elem in trim_list:
        j = j - elem
        if j+k == 0:
            return center + 1  # list index of sequence middle index
        k = k + elem
        center += 1
    return -1  # no match found


def solution(X, A):
    # Break from function because list too small
    if not len(A) > 5:
        return -1

    # zero out non X values into reciprocal for equality approach
    # use deque for efficient 0 index removal Lifo queue also works
    equi_deque = deque(X if elem is X else 0 for elem in A)

    # iterate through deque and pop values if they fail an equality check
    while len(equi_deque) > 4:
        # is_sequence = equality_point(X, equi_deque)
        is_sequence = equi(list(equi_deque))
        # if value did not fail return index
        if is_sequence != -1:
            # use offset to account for prior elements popped
            return len(A) - len(equi_deque) + 1
        equi_deque.popleft()
    return -1
```

Comment: Does B have to be a particular length? (And why are you breaking if len(A) <= 5? Must it be a strict subsequence?)

Comment: @alexwlchan I have the length >= 5 because you can't achieve equality on lists that have an even numbered length and a list can't achieve equality when it is <= 3.

Comment: Is `len(A) % 2` always `True`? I.e. does A always have an odd number of elements?

Comment: @CurtF. The length of List A, the provided argument can be of any size however the sequence that you find will always be odd because you have to split the sequence into 2 distinct lists down the center, dropping the middle index.

Comment: Why can't you achieve equality on lists with length = 3? What is the sum of this list when I remove the middle value `[-1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: How do you know what the "middle" index is when A is even-length?

Comment: @CurtF. `A` does not need to have a middle index, but the question is asking to find a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) that does have a middle index (i.e. odd length) and meets the other requirements. This subsequence may or may not include `A`

Comment: Sorry, should have realized that, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: if `B` is 7 elements wouldn't the index of the middle value +1 be 4, or am I misunderstanding something? Also, why can't you achieve equality with length 3? `[-5,5,5]` remove the middle element gives you `[-5,5]` split `[-5] | [5]` and summing those gives you `0`

Answer (score 2):

Without messing with your actual algorithm, right now it's effectively \$O(n^2)\$.

- Creating the initial `deque` is \$O(n)\$
- The while loop is essentially \$O(n)\$ (worst case)
- Within the while loop you call `equi` with successively smaller lists \$k=(n, n-1, n-2, \dots, n-5)\$ and `equi` is \$O(k)\$ (worst case).

So the loop is \$O(n^2)\$ and dominates.

You **can** get some improvement in running time vs complexity though (maybe 20%) by fixing this line:

```
is_sequence = equi(list(equi_deque))
```

to be

```
is_sequence = equi(equi_deque)
```

The conversion to a list is unnecessary, and is an \$O(k)\$ operation.